# How to make a custom tool tip template in WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a number of buttons on a form (devcomponents `ButtonDropDown` controls to be precise).

I want to show a tool tip for each that contains a header at the top, an image on the left and a description on the right.

The header needs to be tied to the `ButtonDropDown.Header`, the image to the `ButtonDropDown.Image`. I also then need to define the description somewhere.

I've only been using WPF for a few weeks so I've not managed to find any answers via searching, though I have studied a few.

Below is my attempt at creating a template that really doesn't work at all:

```
<Style TargetType="dcr:ButtonDropDown">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="dcr:ButtonDropDown">
                <ContentControl>
                    <ContentControl.ToolTip>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Width="64" Height="32" Margin="3">
                                <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Image}" />
                            </Viewbox>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding ToolTip.Content}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ContentControl.ToolTip>
                </ContentControl>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I then define a button as follows:

```
<dcr:ButtonDropDown Header="-X" Command="{Binding MoveCommand}" CommandParameter="xMinus"
                    ImagePosition="Top" IsEnabled="{Binding UserConfiguration.Move.Visible}"
                    ToolTip="move x axis down">
    <dcr:ButtonDropDown.Image>
        <Viewbox Width="32" Height="32" Margin="3">
            <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource minusXImage}" />
        </Viewbox>
    </dcr:ButtonDropDown.Image>
</dcr:ButtonDropDown>
```

Please could someone give me an idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gone some way to answering this question.

The following style is defined for `ToolTip`:

```
<Style TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate  TargetType="ToolTip">
                <Border Background="GhostWhite" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="1">
                <Grid Background="White">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                           Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ToolTip}}, 
                           Path=PlacementTarget.(dcr:ButtonDropDown.Header)}" 
                           FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Width="64" Height="32" Margin="3">
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ToolTip}}, 
                            Path=PlacementTarget.(dcr:ButtonDropDown.Image)}" />
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                           Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ToolTip}},
                           Path=PlacementTarget.(dcr:ButtonDropDown.ToolTip)}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I then define a button as above and the `ToolTip` text and header appear in the `ToolTip`as required.

The key is the binding:

```
Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type  ToolTip}}, 
Path=PlacementTarget.(dcr:ButtonDropDown.Header)}"
```

Which finds the `Tooltip` as an ancestor of `Label` and casts its `PlacementTarget` into a `ButtonDropDown`

What doesn't work is the image. This appears in the `ToolTip` but is removed from the button.

This will also break any other controls' tooltips if they are not `ButtonDropDown` controls.

I'm beginning to think I'll need to create some custom controls that contain the information I require for the `ToolTip` for each control.